# How to create datetime object from "16SEP2012" in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I can create datetime objects in python this way:

```
import datetime

new_date= datetime.datetime(2012,09,16)
```

How can I create same `datetime` object from a string in this format: `"16SEP2012"` ?

Comment: you need to remove the 0 in '09' for the statement to be valid.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('16Sep2012', '%d%b%Y')
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 16, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional thing to add here- **DateTime Formats**

@falsetru's answer is all good and correct as per what OP asked, though I do feel there's a need to mention DateTime Formats.

So this part inside the function- `'%d%b%Y'`, which is given as a parameter, denotes DateTime format codes. You can access all the types from [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). The table that mentions all the types is towards the bottom of the webpage.

So for example if we need to get a DateTime object for a particular date in a string format. Let's say:

```
>>> date = 'Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0000'
```

The format code would go something like:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_now = datetime.strptime(date, '%a %d %b %Y %X %z')
>>> print(date_now)
2015-05-02 19:54:36+05:30
```

---

**NOTE:** Since there was space between the string values, I am giving space as well. If there's let's a hyphen(-), you can give that instead:

```
>>> date1 = '22-May-2015 19:54:36'
>>> print(datetime.strptime(date1, '%d-%b-%Y %X'))
2015-05-22 19:54:36
```

---

Now once you convert strings into datetime objects, you can perform plethora of things on them. One good example is, like finding the difference between two dates:

```
>>> date1 = 'Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0530'
>>> date2 = 'Fri 01 May 2015 13:54:36 -0000'

>>> first = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a %d %b %Y %X %z')
>>> second = datetime.strptime(date2, '%a %d %b %Y %X %z')

>>> diff = first - second
>>> print(diff.total_seconds())
88200.0
```

I've used this answer multiple times but I usually always had to google for other datetime formats. I hope this would be helpful to someone else as well.